# Adding columns dynamically and inserting data

Tags: postgresql, architecture

Please excuse the vagueness of the question, but databases are not my strong point.

My goal is to implement a very basic file metadata database using postgres. Files may or may not be unique to their related metadata. I.e. A PDF file could be reused but the metadata different for different entries.

From a basic reading of other questions I believe I want at least three tables, with the ID joining the others.

```
Path (1 <-> n) ID (n <-> n) Metadata
```

(If this is an issue, I could probably change the relationship between `ID` and `Metadata` as one-to-many)

However, the interesting part is that the majority of metadata is not known in advance. I want to know if it is feasible to dynamically add and populate columns on the `Metadata` table on update requests. This would allow for basic (if non-performant) searching of the metadata.

Is this even feasible? Or are different more common patterns used and what are they called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not feasible. The best way out is usually to add a `jsonb` column that contains all the odd, rare and dynamic attributes. That solution is quite good as long as you use such attributes in the `SELECT` list or in the `WHERE` condition, but for example trying to join over JSON attributes won't make you happy.

Comment: Thank you, this at least points me in a good direction to delve deeper into the problem. Does the remainder of the proposal seem sane; Using the three tables?

Comment: I didn't properly understand that proposal.

Comment: Fair, I will dig deeper. Thank you anyway